# How to run one protractor test with desktop browser part and mobile browser part

Tags: android, configuration, protractor

There is a protractor test that has two parts:

1. Create a product in **desktop** browser and pass a new product url to the second part.
2. Open the url and buy the product with **mobile** (Android) browser.

Configuration file:

```
exports.config = {
    directConnect : true,
    multiCapabilities : [ {
        browserName : "chrome",
        specs : [ "../specs/browser.js" ],
        count : 1
    }, {
        'browserName' : 'chrome',
        'deviceName' : 'nexus3_arm',
        'platformName' : 'Android',
        'platformVersion' : '5.1.1',
        'udid' : 'emulator-5554',
        specs : [ "../specs/test.js" ],
        count : 1
    } ],
maxSessions : 1,
```

Protractor configuration file has a parameter `directConnect`.

The question is, is it possible to set `directConnect` to false when the second test runs in mobile emulator. Protractor reads a conf file for each capability once again and rewrites all the variables. So it is not possible to set `browserPartEnded = true` and to set `directConnect` parameter to `false` after that.

Also it is not possible to set `directConnect` to false in `onPrepare` function.

Please consider specs files just as tests that open browser only.
For now this configuration opens chrome browser two times in a row.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the Config parameters via `browser.getProcessedConfig()` and then you can set a new value for directConnect (or any other parameter that is set in the Config file).

Try this:

```
it('switches the config parameters', function () {
    browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function (val) {
        console.log(val.directConnect); // logs true
        val.directConnect = false;
        console.log(val.directConnect); // logs false
    });
});
```

Comment: I've tried this code in onPrepare in config file but got the same result: two desktop browsers started one by one. Also added check into specs and get true and false correspondingly. So the browser config was changed but it has no action on actual browser.